# Notation $\gamma$ for Euler's constant $\gamma$.

Tags: math-history, euler-mascheroni-constant

Question. In which book or article George Boole used the notation $\gamma$ for Euler's constant?

Background. Today, Euler's constant is usually denoted by $\gamma$. In 1993 it was found out that the notation $\gamma$ goes back to Carl Anton Bretschneider (1808-1878) (article written in 1835). Now Glaisher writes in "On the history of Euler's constant", 1872:

"Euler’s constant (which throughout this note will be called γ after Mascheroni, De Morgan, &c.) […]
It is clearly convenient that the constant should generally be denoted by the same letter. Euler used C and O for it; Legendre, Lindman, &c., C; De Haan A; and Mascheroni, De Morgan, Boole, &c., have written it γ, which is clearly the most suitable, if it is to have a distinctive letter assigned to it."

Unfortunately, Glaisher is wrong. The notation $\gamma$ appears nowhere in the writings of either Euler or Mascheroni. In 2011 it was discovered that De Morgan used the notation $\gamma$ in 1836:
The differential and integral calculus, Baldwin and Craddock, London 1836

See [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:Euler-Mascheroni-Konstante)

Glaisher wrote "De Morgan, Boole, &c." the advanced question is about the "&c."

Comment: This might be a better fit for [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: It might be a little bit problematic to link a German website dealing with this issue on a mainly English speaking site as MSE. However, as already pointed out by *Theo Benedit* this question would be more likely to get answered on HSM Stack Exchange and I would recommend to repost it there aswell.

Comment: For A.De Moran see [The differential and integral calculus (1836), page 578](https://books.google.it/books?id=95x4IrIcHrgC&pg=PA578).